# When I filter data on Vega-Lite it only is able to filter specific values

Tags: vega-lite

I have been trying to make a choropleth map data visualization using Vega-Lite; however, I have run into some weird errors when attempting to filter my data.

Some background, my data provides information about global health information from years 2000 to 2015.

When I run the visualisations without adding the filter, it displays data of the life expectancy for the year 2000 only. But after adding the filter (I tried filtering by the year 2000 and even tried filtering by country China), the map is still present but no data is dislpayed.

[When not filtering/ filtering for "equal": 2000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JOKN.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@5.22.1"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-lite@5.2.0"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@6.20.8"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="vis"/>
    <script>
        const spec = {
    "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
    "title": "Global Life Expectancy (2015)",
    "width": 800,
    "height": 400,
    "data": {
        "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FIT3179/Vega-Lite/main/3_choropleth_map/js/ne_110m_admin_0_countries.topojson",
        "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "ne_110m_admin_0_countries"}
    },
    "projection": {"type": "equalEarth"},
    "layer": [
        {
            "transform": [
                {
                    "calculate": "'Data is not available in ' + datum.properties.NAME",
                    "as": "note"
                }
            ],
            "mark": {"type": "geoshape", "fill": "lightgray", "stroke": "white"},
            "encoding": {"tooltip": {"field": "note"}}
        },
        {
            "data": {
                "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FIT3179/Vega-Lite/main/7_others/oceans.topojson",
                "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "oceans"}
            },
            "mark": {"type": "geoshape", "fill": "skyblue"}
        },
        {
            "data": {
            "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FIT3179/Vega-Lite/main/2_symbol_map/js/WorldMapWithGraticules.topojson",
            "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "ne_110m_graticules_30"}
        },
        "mark": {"type": "geoshape", "fill": null, "stroke": "lightgray"}
        },
        {
            "transform": [
                {
                    "lookup": "properties.NAME",
                    "from": {
                        "data": {
                            // "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FIT3179/Vega-Lite/main/3_choropleth_map/data/covid_10_10_2020.csv"
                            "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GarretYong/FIT3179/main/Week%2010/Life%20Expectancy%20Data.csv" 
                        },
                        "key": "Country",
                        // "fields": ["Active", "Confirmed", "Population"]
                        "fields": ["Year", "Life expectancy "]
                    },
                },
                {
                    "filter": { // THE ISSUE starts here ================================================================
                        "timeUnit": "year",
                        "field": "Year",
                        "equal": 2001
                    }
                    // "filter": {
                    //     "field": "source.Country",
                    //     "equal": "China"
                    // }
                }
            ],
            "mark": {"type": "geoshape", "stroke": "white"},
            "encoding": {
                "color": {
                    // "field": "Confirmed per 10,000 population",
                    // "field": "Active",
                    "field": "Life expectancy ",
                    "type": "quantitative",
                    "scale": {
                        "type": "threshold",
                        "domain": [50,60,70,80,90],
                        "range": ["#372801", "#553901", "#7b5001","#9f6501","#c77c01","#ff9e00"]
                    }
                },
                "tooltip": [
                    {"field": "properties.NAME", "type": "nominal", "title": "Country"},
                    {"field": "Life expectancy ", "type": "quantitative"}
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "transform": [
                {
                    "lookup": "properties.NAME",
                    "from": {
                        "data": {
                            "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FIT3179/Vega-Lite/main/3_choropleth_map/data/countryInfo.csv"
                        },
                        "key": "name",
                        "fields": ["latitude", "longitude"]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "mark": {"type": "text"},
            "encoding": {
                "longitude": {"field": "longitude", "type": "quantitative"},
                "latitude": {"field": "latitude", "type": "quantitative"},
                "text": {"field": "properties.NAME", "type": "nominal"},
                "opacity": {
                "condition": {
                    "test": "datum['properties.NAME'] == 'China' || datum['properties.NAME'] == 'Brazil' || datum['properties.NAME'] == 'Australia' || datum['properties.NAME'] == 'Malaysia' ||  datum['properties.NAME'] == 'Yemen' ||  datum['properties.NAME'] == 'United States of America'",
                    "value": 1
                },
                "value": 0
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "config": {}
};
    vegaEmbed("#vis", spec, {mode: "vega-lite"}).then(console.log).catch(console.warn);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I filter for year 2000, it works as expected but when I change the value to 2001 and above, the data will no longer display.
[after setting to "equal": 2001](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGNkC.png)

I would really appreciate any help and I want to say thank you in advance for your time.

I checked online for other similar threads but not quite the answer I was looking for. I tried to verify the data type where I would use something like "lte": 2015 and it still works (but only displays 2000 data and "gt": 2001 will not display any data) so it should be int type. I tried using generative AI like bard to help debug and still didn't work. Tried asking my school's forums but lecturers are quite tight lipped.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out what was wrong with my visualization, I realized that I joined the data wrongly.

Initially, I joined the data by initializing the topojson data first then only initializing my own custom data and since the data is supposed to be joined by country, it only has one row of data.

For instance,

```
Food   | Country                 Country    | Date
===================     joins    ==================
Apple  | China                   China      | 2015
Kiwi   | Australia               China      | 2014
                                 Australia  | 2015
```

You will get

```
Food   | Country    | Date
============================
Apple  | China      | 2015
Kiwi   | Australia  | 2015
```

So in order to solve it, I initialised my own custom data first before the topojson to avoid a Left Join error